# select with subquery with filters in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join

[image: Current output(wrong)][image: Business requirement]

I have the following code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
    tctc_cntipcli as "Type of contract" ,
    texe_cncclipu as "Contract number",
    TCTC_CNDOCIDC as "Client name", 
    tsrv_cndesser as "Service name", 
    texe_cnfuncid as "Service number", 
    tsrs_cnsubsdc as "Subservice name", 
    texe_cnsubser as "Subservice number", 
    tmap_cndesc as "Map",

    ( 
        SELECT to_char(count(tlof_cnlofrid)) 
        from service.kndtlof
        where   
            tlof_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu and
            tlof_cnservic = texe_cnfuncid and
            tlof_cnsubser = texe_cnsubser and
            tlof_cnfhalta > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
    ) as "Volume of files messages" ,
    (
        select count(it.int_tran_id)
        from internal_transactions it
        join status ss on ss.int_tran_id = it.int_tran_id
        join app_data ad on it.int_tran_id in 
        (
            select distinct ad.int_tran_id
            from app_data
            where app_data.add_info_table in ('ACH', 'Wire')
        )
        join service.kndtexe ke on it.debit_acct in 
        (
            select distinct texe_cnasupro
            from service.kndtexe ke
            where 
                (
                    (ke.texe_cnfuncid = '3001' and ke.texe_cnsubser = 'W1')
                    or
                    (ke.texe_cnfuncid = '3085' and ke.texe_cnsubser = 'I%')
                )
        )
        where it.entry_timestamp > trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
    ) as "Volume of payments"
from 
    service.kndtctc, 
    service.kndtexe, 
    service.kndtscm, 
    service.kndtsrv, 
    service.kndtsrs, 
    service.kndtmap
where 
    tctc_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
    and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
    and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser 
    and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
    and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
    and tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco
    and tscm_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
    and tscm_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
    and tctc_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and texe_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and tsrv_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and tsrs_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and tscm_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and tmap_cnestado in ('01', '03')
    and tctc_cncclipu in ('50008753')
order by tctc_cncclipu;
```

The second subquery is querying from the transaction db to the service db(see Business requirement image) and needs to check against the texe table for any accounts tied to the contract that fall under the contract number in tctc and output only for 3001/W1 OR 3085/I%. How can i filter the subquery to achieve this?

Comment: Try formatting your code so people can read it.  Explicit `join` is a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly place surround the query using

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
------------------
SELECT DISTINCT    tctc_cntipcli as "Type of contract" ,
                       texe_cncclipu as "Contract number",
                       TCTC_CNDOCIDC as "Client name", 
                       tsrv_cndesser as "Service name", 
                       texe_cnfuncid as "Service number", 
                       tsrs_cnsubsdc as "Subservice name", 
                       texe_cnsubser as "Subservice number", 
                       tmap_cndesc as "Map",

           ( 
            SELECT to_char(count(tlof_cnlofrid)) 
            from service.kndtlof
            where   tlof_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
            and     tlof_cnservic = texe_cnfuncid
            and     tlof_cnsubser = texe_cnsubser
            and     tlof_cnfhalta > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
           ) as "Volume of files messages" ,

         (select count(it.int_tran_id)
         from internal_transactions it
         join status ss on ss.int_tran_id = it.int_tran_id
         join app_data ad on it.int_tran_id in 
(select distinct ad.int_tran_id                                                                               from app_data
where app_data.add_info_table in ('ACH', 'Wire')
)
join service.kndtexe ke on it.debit_acct in 
(select distinct texe_cnasupro
from service.kndtexe ke
where ( 
(ke.texe_cnfuncid = '3001' and ke.texe_cnsubser = 'W1')
or
(ke.texe_cnfuncid = '3085' and ke.texe_cnsubser = 'I%')
)
                                                                                         )
where it.entry_timestamp > trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
                                           ) as "Volume of payments"

from service.kndtctc, service.kndtexe, service.kndtscm, service.kndtsrv, service.kndtsrs, service.kndtmap
                              where tctc_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
                              and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
                              and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser 
                              and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                              and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
                              and tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco
                              and tscm_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
                              and tscm_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                              and tctc_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and texe_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and tsrv_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and tsrs_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and tscm_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and tmap_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                              and tctc_cncclipu in ('50008753')
                              order by tctc_cncclipu
------------------
    ) WHERE "Volume of payments" > 0
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: what would the from clause be?

Comment: whole query without ;  ?

Comment: anyone can help please?

Comment: and where is the issue? is there any exception? (should be not; assuming the original query was ok)

Comment: the problem is with that count in the second subquery not co-relating to the outer query per the filters placed there.

Comment: so it looks like you need to adjust where it.entry_timestamp > trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and add some correlating condition. What it would be?

Comment: i need to tie the acct# from the "it" table to the "texe" table in the other database(service) and filter according to the texe_cnfuncid and texe_cnsubser where only 3001/3085 and W1/I% return values for that subquery.

Comment: so the the adjustments of wehre clausule would be ke.somekey = service.kndtexe.somekey ?

Comment: ke is in the service db and is the alias for kndtexe ... this db is where the cncclipu, cnasupro, cnfuncid, cnsubser, etc fields are stored. the only thing to link back the internal_transactions it from the tran db to the service db is the it.debit_acct which co-relates to the texe_cnasupro. As you can see the main select is all fields in the service db, but the last query for the count is querying the tran db field count.

Comment: Just that you are querying the exe table 3 times. Thought you are missing a link between inner and outer query.

Comment: yes so i would need to relate the cnasupro from the "it" table to the cncclipu, cnfuncid, cnsubser, cnasupro in the "texe"table...is what i am thinking?

Comment: index texe_pk has columns cncclipu, cnasupro

Comment: where it.entry_timestamp > trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and KETOP.cncclipu = ke.cncclipu and KETOP.cnasupro = ke.cnasupro

Comment: from service.kndtctc, service.kndtexe KETOP